# Trying to access s3 bucket using scala application

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I want to access amazon s3 bucket using scala application. I have set up the scala IDE in my eclipse. But when i try to run the >application on my local (Run As --> Scala Application) , it gives the following >error on the console. Error: Could not find or load main class org.test.spark1.test I an trying to run  a simple wordcount application in which i am accessing a >file that is stored in my S3 bucket and storing the results in another file. Please make me understand what might the problem be.

Note: I am using eclipse maven project. My scala application code is :

```
package org.test.spark1
import com.amazonaws._
import com.amazonaws.auth._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.amazonaws.services.s3._
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest
import java.io.File;
object test extends App {
def main(args: Array[String])  {
val myAccessKey = "here is my key"
val mySecretKey = "here is my secret key"
val bucket = "nlp.spark.apps"
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sample")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val yourAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(myAccessKey, mySecretKey)
val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(yourAWSCredentials)
// This will create a bucket for storage
amazonS3Client.createBucket("nlp-spark-apps2")
val s3data = sc.textFile("here is my url of text file")
s3data.flatMap(line =>
  line.split(" "))
  .map(word =>
    (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ * _)
  .saveAsTextFile("/home/hadoop/cluster-code2.txt")
}}
```

Comment: There's no need for both `test extends App` and a `main` method. Choose either one.

Comment: i removed extends App from the code.. but the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I came across is that the Scala IDE does not automatically detect your main class:

1. Go to Menu --> "Run" --> "Run configurations"
2. Click on "Scala    application" and on the icon for "New launch configuration"
3. For    project select your project and for the main class (that for some    reason is not auto-detected) manually enter (in your case)    org.test.spark1.test
4. Apply and Run

**OR**

You could try to run your Spark job locally without eclipse using spark-submit.

```
spark-submit --class org.test.spark1.test --master local[8] {path to assembly jar}
```

Another thing, you should never hardcode your AWS credentials. I suggest you use [InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html). This credentials exist in the instance metadata associated with the IAM role for the EC2 instance.